# Unable to drop table inside a transaction

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to execute the following in MySQL but I keep getting an error:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS course_grade_swap;
COMMIT;
```

The error states:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-3 --------------------------
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS course_grade_swap;
COMMIT' at line 2
```

I'm not sure what the problem is here. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if it is related to your error, but placing `DROP TABLE` in a transaction is _useless_ anyway  as it is a *[Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/implicit-commit.html)*.

Comment: I don't think a `DROP TABLE` works in a commit.

Comment: No DDL statement can be used in a transaction. They all cause any open transaction to commit.

Comment: However, issuing a `DROP` command inside a transaction shouldn't cause a syntax error, just an implicit commit. Where are you executing this? Is it via an API that doesn't support multiple statements at once?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski may be on to something. While it's not exactly the same, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a557f/1) didn't give me an error.

Comment: @McAdam331 attempted to reproduce locally (`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`) - works like a charm, no syntax error.

Comment: @Mureinik I didn't mention in the comments, but I verified that initially too on mariadb

Comment: Why are you even using transaction for this? This cannot be rolled back anyways. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46599/transaction-rollback-on-drop-database . Also, what is the MYSQL version? This seems to be running just fine on 5.5